# Change value of variable with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I regularly need to change the values of a variable based on the values on a different variable, like this:

```
mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl == 4] <- NA
```

I tried doing this with `dplyr` but failed miserably:

```
mtcars %>%
mutate(mpg = mpg == NA[cyl == 4]) %>%
as.data.frame()
```

How could I do this with `dplyr`?

Answer (score 369, accepted):

We can use `replace` to change the values in 'mpg' to `NA` that corresponds to `cyl==4`.

```
mtcars %>%
     mutate(mpg=replace(mpg, cyl==4, NA)) %>%
     as.data.frame()
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is another option using a simple `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(mpg = ifelse(cyl == 4, NA, mpg))
```

Output head:

```
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710            NA   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

Another option could be using [`case_when`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) which could be extended to more conditions:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(mpg = case_when(cyl == 4 ~ NA,
                         TRUE ~ mpg))
```