# Conditionally replace values in one column with values from another column using dplyr

Tags: r, replace, dplyr, conditional-statements

I want to replace the values in one column that match a certain condition with values in that same row from a different column. Consider this example:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tribble(
  ~X25, ~Other,
  "a", NA,
  "b", NA,
  "Other", "c",
  "Other", "d"
)
View(data)

# Works to change values in X25
within(data, {
    X25 <- ifelse(X25 == "Other", Other, X25)
})

# Changes values in X25 to NA and doesn't replace X25 with appropriate value from Other column
data %>% mutate(X25 = replace(X25, X25 == "Other", Other))
```

The code using "within" works well. How can I use dplyr if needed (as part of a longer mutate / summarise process)?

Edit: This is a different scenario from [Change value of variable with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013850/change-value-of-variable-with-dplyr). I don't want to blindly assign all matching cells with the same value (e.g., NA). I wanted to pull them from another particular column.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With `replace`, the lengths should be the same, so we need to subset the `Other` as well with the logical expression

```
data %>%
    mutate(X25 = replace(X25, X25 == "Other", Other[X25=="Other"]))
```

---

Another option would be `case_when`

```
data %>%
     mutate(X25 = case_when(X25=="Other"~ Other,
                            TRUE ~ X25))
```

Or `ifelse`

```
data %>%
    mutate(X25 = ifelse(X25 == "Other", Other, X25))
```

Comment: @stevec yes, you are right.  In general, it would be better to convert `factor` to `character` before doing the. conversion or use `ifelse(as.character(X25) == "Other", as.character(Other), as.character(X25)))` or else have to add `levels` (if there are some new levels) before the conversion in `case_when` etc