# How to assign categories based on subcategories

Tags: r

I have a set of data with a column of category and another column of subcategory. However, some of the category data is incorrect. I want to fix those incorrect category data based on subcategories.

For example, we have two categories: A and B with subcategories A_sub and B_sub. However, one of the entries for category is mistakenly input as "Others" but with a subcategory of "A_sub" (see code below). Is there any elegant way to change "Others" to "A" under the category column?

```
data <- data.frame("category" = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "Others", "Others"), "subcategory" = c("A_sub", "B_sub", "A_sub", "A_sub", "A_sub", "A_sub"))
```

The expected output is:

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EF7i.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for including a reproducible example! What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: Base r answer `data$category[data$category == "Others"] <- "A"`

Comment: Also, this a duplicate of the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28013895/5874001)

Comment: I tried to manually correct it in excel since there are only 140 categories, but wondering if there is a elegant way in r to do it faster. The issue I am having right now is to find a quick way to create the backwards mapping (from subcategory to category). ie. how to automatically identify the correct category based on other subcategories that have the correct category mapping.

Comment: Thanks @InfiniteFlashChess, maybe I am misleading a little bit in the sample code. I changed it so that the 3rd row has the wrong category too. So essentially, I am trying to figure out how to check if the mapping between category and subcategory is correct. The actual data has 140 categories. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming I know the subcategories are all correct.

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr you can use ifelse statements inside of a mutate statement. So you could so something like:

```
data <- data %>%
dplyr::mutate(category = ifelse(category=="A" & subcategory=="Other", "A_sub", .$subcategory)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you know that subcategory is correct, why not just take the A/B from the subcategory string and replace the category, like this:

```
data %>% mutate(category = sub("_.*", "",subcategory))
```